# Gridview rowupdate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using gridview_rowupdating.Of the 6 columns in the table, two columns contains null values and when edit button is clicked, users will enter an integer in the Rate column.Once update is clicked the value must be posted back to gridview. I am having problem in rowupdating event. I am getting below mentioned error message.

```
 //Retrieve the table from the session object.
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["datasource"];

    //Update the values.           
    GridViewRow row = GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Rate"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[5].Controls[0])).Text;
           //Reset the edit index.
    GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();

    Session["datasource"] = dt;
```

Error:
: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.'
But this error doesnt make any sense. I am entering integer for the column Rate.

Comment: The error looks like an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, which means that one of your indices is off. What line throws the exception? Could you include a full stacktrace?

Comment: dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Rate"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[5].Controls[0])).Text; this is the line that throw error. I tried parsing, but not working

Comment: In that case the most likely culprit is `row.Cells[5]`. Could you add the markup for the gridview?

Comment: will edit the question posted

Comment: sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView2.DataBind();
                    myConnection2.Close();
                    Session["datasource"] = dt;
                    BindData();

Comment: this grid is simple selection from table. but the problem is the column i am trying to update. Its null when retrieved from database, but when user clicks edit, i have to get the value and store.

Comment: I was thinking of the .aspx markup containing the gridview column templates. The error indicates that either `dt.Rows.Count <= row.DataItemIndex`, or `row.Cells.Count <= 5`. If the cell count is off, it should be visible in the markup.

Comment: If the datatable column at index 5 (Rate) is of integer datatype then you cannot assign to it a string (the Text property). You need to convert that string in an integer

Comment: <asp:BoundField DataField="full_name" readonly="true" HeaderText="full_name" SortExpression="full_name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="total_hours" readonly="true" HeaderText="total_hours" SortExpression="total_hours" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Month" readonly="true" HeaderText="Month" SortExpression="Month" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Year" readonly="true" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="rate" readonly="false" HeaderText="Rate" SortExpression="Rate" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="bill" readonly="true" HeaderText="Bill" SortExpression="Bill" />

Comment: @JananiSendhilKumar do not put code in comments. It is pretty underadable. Instead [edit] your question adding the code

Comment: i am sorry. i am relatively new to this.i am mba student , coding in summer internship, learning asp.net on the go.

Comment: @Steve Assigning something of the wrong type would result in an `InvalidCastException` cf. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The cell collection on the gridview row is zero indexed, so the 5th column from your gridview "Rate", is actually at index 4. Try this:

```
//Retrieve the table from the session object.
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["datasource"];

//Update the values.      
DataRow dataRow = dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex];    
dataRow["Rate"] = Int32.Parse(e.NewValues["Rate"].ToString());

GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
//Bind data to the GridView control.
BindData();

Session["datasource"] = dt;
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this with and without parsing.Without parsing, this is the error message: Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <> in rate Column.  Expected type is Int32.'                                                  
 With parsing:System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: @JananiSendhilKumar I've updated the answer to make it clearer what is failing. Would you try again, and note which line is now causing the error?

Comment: dataRow["Rate"] = txtRate.Text; this is failing

Comment: The new error is different from what you originally posted. The new error `Couldn't store <> in rate Column. Expected type is Int32` indicates what Ben and Steve have mentioned in an answer and a comment. Namely that the type of "Rate" in your datatable is int, but you are attempting to set it to a string. I will update the answer with code to parse the int from the textbox. `System.FormatException` indicates that the value from the textboxis not a valid integer. What are you typing in the box?

Comment: just a number. eg: 10,32

Comment: Your'e welcome. Are you still getting the same error without a decimal point? Using eg. `42`, and including the `Int32.Parse`call?

Comment: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format. 'dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["rate"] = Int32.Parse(((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text);

Comment: @JananiSendhilKumar I've updated the answer with an alternate solution. If your problem persists, you should probably get a debugger attached, and see what the value of the text field is. It seems that you have a reference to the correct field, but somehow the value is not being propagated.

Answer (score -1):

When Rate has the type int and

```
((TextBox)(row.Cells[5].Controls[0])).Text
```

is string, it can't work. Try parsing the text to int.

Comment: Assigning something of the wrong type would result in an `InvalidCastException`cf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5(v=vs.110).aspx